# Accessing controller in Cucumber to test sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

First off - I know that this is generally horrible practice, because Cucumber is meant to only test outputs. I just want to do this for one veryveryvery specific case.

I have an app that handles user authentication using a cookie set by another app I maintain. I'd like to write a very simple integration test for authentication:

```
Given I have logged as "some_user" on the SSO server
When I visit any page
Then I should be logged in as "some_user"
```

My current step definition for the Then is as follows:

```
Then /^I should be logged in as "([^"]*)"$/ do |username|
  user = User.find_by_username(username)
  assert_equal @controller.current_user, user
end
```

Obviously, this is failing with "Undefined method 'current_user' for nil:NilClass".

In case it's not obvious - ApplicationController#current_user returns either the user currently logged in or nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit some page where currently logged on user's name is displayed.
Like:
`When I go to the account page`
`Then I should see "Welcome user" within "div#login"`

Comment: I'd considered doing this - the app's header displays different things to a logged-in user - but it feels brittle and hacky to me. I'd rather test that someplace else/in addition to testing, directly, whether a user is logged in.

Comment: Why do you think it is hacky? If you would test your application in browser, I mean simulating a real user, how would you check current logged on user? I think that's what Cucumber is for, simulating real clicks.

Comment: The indirection of it bothers me? Which may be a personal style thing that I need to get over. The reason it feels *brittle,* though, as opposed to hacky, is that then it becomes more sensitive (& maybe oversensitive) to precisely what the user header looks like at any time - b/c since it's a user switching *back* to the main app from an SSO/user db management app, there isn't really a welcome-type page that they see.